# QCommandLinkButton Bottom Cut Off

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator

In Qt/QtCreator I have come across a problem that I cannot seem to fix. I have 3 QCommandLinkButtons in a vertical layout. In the designer everything seems fine and I have it the way I want it, like this:

[image]

When I run the application though it looks very different.

[image]

At first glance it may look fine, but upon further inspection you can see that the icon is cut off as well as the description. I have tried setting minimum sizes on these buttons as well as putting them in different types of layouts, and none of that worked. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: This only happens when I have these in a QWizard. Just tried a regular dialog, and it worked fine.

Comment: What version of Qt are you using? I just tried creating them on a empty form with vertical layout and it seems to work fine for me. They only cut when my form's height is not enough for them

Comment: Could you post some code where we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Create a new project & see if same happens, group the `QCommandLinkButtons ` in to a `QGridLayout` and see what happens

Comment: This only happens when I have these in a QWizard. Just tried a regular dialog, and it worked fine.